# Tiled window switcher

Tags: window-manager

I'm a big iTerm user with 3 split panes on a 30" monitor. The only issue is that I sometimes want to add a Safari window as the left most pane. I can achieve this by using any of the window sizers out there and setting the window to float on top. However, this means that I have to <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> to get to the Safari window while I <kbd>⌘</kbd>+arrow to switch between the panes.

Is there a program that not only uses a grid for positioning/sizing, but also provides directional navigation between panes?

Answer (score 1):

I found [Slate](https://github.com/jigish/slate) which might fit the bill. I've tried out the following ~/.slate and it does directional focus. Will check back after playing with it before selecting this answer.

```
# Focus Bindings
# NOTE: some of these may *not* work if you have not removed the expose/spaces/mission control bindings
bind right:cmd    focus right
bind left:cmd     focus left
bind up:cmd       focus up
bind down:cmd     focus down
bind up:cmd;alt   focus behind
bind down:cmd;alt focus behind
```